# How to pass output from remote script to local script in bash

Tags: bash, logging, echo, output

I have a bash script that automatically connects to a remote location and runs another script that is stored at the remote location. In the script on the remote location, I want to have my autoconnect script (which is stored on my local pc) capture specific output that is echoed out from the remote script so I can store it in a separate log. I know that something will need to be placed on the remote script that redirects the output so the local script can catch it, I'm just not sure where to go. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

On your local script, in your ssh line, you can redirect some of the outputs to a file with `tee`:

```
ssh ... | tee -a output.log
```

If you want to filter which one goes to the output.log file, you can use process substitution:

```
ssh .... | tee >(grep "Some things you want to filter." >> output.log)
```

Besides grep you can use other commands as well like awk.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using the tee command already in my local script to echo the entire output to a log. However, there's certain output I need to capture to store in an error log. I like the idea of using grep, but then I'd have to customize the output to include a certain keyword. Which is what I thought to go with initially, but I want to see if there's a better method of doing this.